# How to check the value?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how to set the condition in the IF loop for the value of NN010102, and to check only the last two digits? If 01 is to print something, or if 02 is to print something else.
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you search thoroughly and give it a try yourself and get back here with any problem if you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
string test = "NN010102";

if(test.EndsWith("01"))
{
    //print something
}
else if(test.EndsWith("02"))
{
    //print something else
}
else
{
    //error handling?
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried using Substring but did not work for both values.

Comment: And how can I check at the same time for only 01 value? For example, if it is the only value.

Comment: Just remove the `else if`block

Comment: I apologize, I did not precisely ask the question. How to check the value 01, and print a print out( //print something else) of the conditions 02?

Comment: Maybe it would he more helpfull when you would read something like this [if-else condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else). No offence but it seems like you need some base knowledge.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I have basic knowledge, but the whole story is a bit broad, so I can not give details.

Comment: Maybe you'll get more/better help when asking a new question where you try to explain what you want to achieve. Try to abstract as much as you have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
string foo = "NN010102";
foo.EndsWith("01") ? print1 : print2;
```